Is it possible (and how) to make displaying details lazy loading in {reactable}?
I have a shiny app which stores a names of data frames. This names work as a SQL queries - when user clicks on the name, it should run the query and display result. I thought that I could use for that {reactable} to store the names and details parameter to call a function which runs a query ({DBI}). But what I want is to compute the query only when user clicks the name / row (I don't even want to store the result - if user closes the details of row, results should be garbage collected).
I know that {shiny} is based on lazy loading paradigm so I thought it will be easy. Here is an example code:
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  reactable::reactableOutput("tbl")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$tbl <- reactable::renderReactable({
    data_df <- data.frame(row = c("iris", "mtcars"))
    reactable::reactable(data_df,
                         details = function(val) {
                           reactable::reactable(get(data_df$row[[val]],
                                                    envir = rlang::pkg_env("datasets")))
                         })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)


However, my attempts show that everything is computed when the table is created - so taking above example - code reactable::reactable(get(data_df$row[[val]], envir = rlang::pkg_env("datasets"))) from both rows were computed on app start, not only when users click on the name to display details of row (I know that, because I have used some heavy loading SQL query). Is there a way to (preferably easy) turn this behavior to be lazy loading? My real app has dynamic data - number of rows / names / queries changes depending on what user is doing.

consider defining data_df as a event driven object.  For example, data_df <- eventReactive(input$user_selection, {... }).  Then just use data_df() in output$tbl.
